# Insert ActiveX Control in Excel using Excel JavaScript API while creating Excel-Web-AddIns

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I am developing a Excel-Web-AddIns Project and I want to bind data in Excel ActiveX control using Excel JavaScript API.

Is it possible to create ActiveX control in Excel using Excel JavaScript API?
Please share code, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API in Excel.js to create an ActiveX control. ActiveX is for Windows only. Excel Web Add-ins are for cross-platform add-ins.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is is possible to create ComboBox or custom control using Excel .js. I want to convert Excel cell into Combo Box or add combo box for a cell.

Comment: No. That's not possible either.